# Cardinality of the set of automorphisms of $(\mathbb{N},+)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, permutations

I wonder if the set of bijections $\sigma\,:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ that satisfy

$$
\sigma(a+b) = \sigma(a)+\sigma(b)\qquad \forall a,b\in\mathbb{N}
$$

is countable or uncountable. What if we also ask

$$
\sigma(ab) = \sigma(a)\sigma(b)\qquad\forall a,b\in\mathbb{N}
$$

I know that if we just ask bijection there are uncountable many of them, but i wonder if with these restrictions we get just countable many.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you please give an example of such a bijection which is not the identity map?

Comment: He cannot give such an example, right ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we use the convention that $0 \in \Bbb N$, we have
$$\sigma(0) = \sigma(0 + 0) = \sigma(0) + \sigma(0),$$
so
$$\sigma(0) = 0.$$
So, for either convention, it's enough to find bijections from $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ to itself.

Now, we have that $$\sigma(a + 1) = \sigma(a) + \sigma(1) > \sigma(a),$$
that is, that $\sigma$ is strictly increasing. Using that $\sigma$ must be a bijective immediately (or inductively) gives that $$\sigma(n) = n$$
for all $n$, that is, the only such bijection satisfying the criterion is the identity.

Of course, this bijection also satisfies the condition
$$\sigma(ab) = \sigma(a) \sigma(b).$$

Comment: In conclusion (answering the OP's question), the set of bijections is finite(ly countable), namely, it has a cardinality of 1.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** First show that $\sigma(1)=1$, then proceed by induction.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one bijection $\sigma: \mathbb N_{> 0} \rightarrow \mathbb N_{> 0}$ s.t. $\sigma(a+b) = \sigma(a)+ \sigma(b)$, namely the identity:

Suppose not, then there is a least $a$ s.t. $\sigma(a) \neq a$. As this is impossible for $a=1$, we have $\sigma(a-1) = a-1$ and $\sigma(1) = 1$ and thus $\sigma(a) = \sigma( (a-1)+1) = \sigma(a-1) + \sigma(1) = a-1 + 1 = a$. (Contradiction)